# Hex color from php variable wont set as background

Tags: php, css

So the user has the option to pick up a hex color which goes into the db. PHP script gets that value and there starts the problem. Background just stays blank. Here is the code:

```
  $hex=78FFDB; 
    if ($hex != NULL or $hex != ""){
    $body="<body style='background:#$hex;'></body>";
    $stat="#$hex runs";
    }
echo $body;
```

Comment: you need quotes `$hex='78FFDB';` your code shouldn't be working at all because it is a syntax error.

Comment: Still doesn't work ??

Comment: Tried `$body="<body style='background:#" . $hex . ";'></body>";` ?

Comment: That isn't working too :(

Comment: WHat do you get with this: `$body="<body style='background:#$hex;'>content</body>";` ?

Comment: only the white background...

Comment: maybe update edit your answer and let us see your current code and then see what firebug or something says about the html output.

Comment: ok so i get hex value from db using while loop $hex=$row['hex'];...then this code runs if ($hex != NULL or $hex != ""){
$body="<body style='background:#$hex;'>&nbsp;</body>";
$stat="#$hex runs";
} ... i am not really sure what's going wrong

Comment: so what does the html output look like?

Comment: i've done it i forgot to echo the body variable :D thanks for help :D

Comment: but you wrote it in your question?

Comment: yeah i know but it seems that i've accidently removed it afterwards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your `$hex` needs quotation.

```
<?php
$hex="78FFDB"; 
if ($hex != NULL or $hex != ""){
    $body="<body style='background:#$hex;'></body>";
    $stat="#$hex runs";
}
echo $body;
?>
```

Then your `<body>` is maybe not visible because there is no content so you should first try to add some content

```
$body="<body style='background:#$hex;'>some content</body>";
```

and see if there is background color where the content is.

If you need a full screen background what ever content is displayed use this css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your hex value is not in a string, so PHP is trying to interpret the letters as a number, and it fails there. Try this

```
<?php
$hex="78FFDB"; 
    if ($hex != NULL or $hex != ""){
    $body="<body style='background:#$hex;'></body>";
    $stat="#$hex runs";
    }
echo $body;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no content in background, so there is nothing to show background with.
Try adding `&nbsp; before </body>`, and see if it works. Also, make sure that $hex= is a string in quotation marks.

Comment: What is the resultant HTML source code as visible by client? (Ctrl+U)

Answer (score 0):

I am giving an example save the following code as index.php in your directory.If you use wamp server so put that index.php file in the following directory **C:\wamp\www\hex\index.php**  and run it from the server .
Here hex is your folder name.Hope it will work on your system.

```
<?php  $hex="78FFDB";
    if ($hex != NULL or $hex != ""){
    $body="<body style='background:#$hex;'></body>";
    $stat="#$hex runs";
    }
echo $body;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Selectors
</title>
<style>

div {
   width:1000px;
   border:2px solid #000;
}
 .divone{
      background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0%,gray 100%);
 }
 .divone ~ div{
      background-image:radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%,red 0%,gray 100%);
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fancy bold">
        This is the type selectors used in css.
    </div>

   <div class="divone">
                                                                                                                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    </div>
          <div><h1>Hello World!</h1></div>
       <div>
                                                                                                                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]